# How to identify Tenured Space

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

I want to build a MemoryWarningSystem as described in many articles:
e.g. as in http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue092.html.

Therefore, I want to identify the tenured space like this:

```
    private MemoryPoolMXBean findTenuredGenPool() {
        for (MemoryPoolMXBean pool : ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans()) {

                 if(pool is tenured space)
                    return tenured

        }
    }
```

I have seen two different ways to identify tenured space

1. Check if pool name equals to "PS Old Gen" and/or "Tenured Gen".
2. Check whether "`pool.getType() == MemoryType.HEAP  && pool.isUsageThresholdSupported()`"

**Problem with 1**: What about CMS Old Gen? What about other tenured spaces? Should I add all of them to the List of Tenured Names?

**Problem with 2**: Is this a "safe" way of retrieving the tenured space? Is it reliable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For HotSpot JVM possible memory pool name for old space

- `Tenured Gen`
- `PS Old Gen`
- `CMS Old Gen`
- `G1 Old Gen`

For JRockit

- `Old Space`